# Http request on Android10 which connect to IoT device host

Tags: http, xamarin.android, wifi, android-10.0

I'm using new WiFi network specifier API to connect android10 with IoT host device AP mode, every thing is connecting work fine with specified SSID name of IoT device by using below code.

```
var specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
    .SetSsid(deviceSSID)
    .SetWpa2Passphrase(devicePassword)
    .Build();

var myrequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
    .AddTransportType(TransportType.Wifi) 
    .RemoveCapability(NetCapability.Internet) 
    .SetNetworkSpecifier(specifier) 
    .Build();

var connectivityManager = this.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService) as ConnectivityManager;
connectivityManager.RequestNetwork(myrequest , _callback);
```

After, that I'm trying to make http request with below code.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.1/info");
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

The results are always failed request by timeout exception.

On the other hand if I'm back to use manual Android phone setting to connect this SSID (not use programmatically connect by network specifier API) above code http request is work fine every times.

Do you know why http request with WiFI network specifier is failed ? What is difference between this WiFI network specifier and manual android setting connect ?

Regards,